# Do there exist non-trivial integer coefficients that break linear independence of the roots of unity?

Tags: linear-algebra, roots-of-unity

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $k=0,\cdots,n-1$, $\omega_k=e^{\tfrac{2\pi i}{n}k}$ be the roots of unity, $c_k \in \mathcal{Z}$ be integer coefficients, trivial and non-trivial be two subcategories for $c_k$ defined as follows: Trivial is when $c_k$ contains equal integers that are evenly spaced under modulo addition of a composite divisor of $n$, and non-trivial $c_k$ is when evenly spaced integers under modulo addition of a composite divisor of $n$ are not equal. An example of a trivial case for $n=6$ is
$$
(2)\omega_0+(2)\omega_1+(1)\omega_2+(2)\omega_3+(2)\omega_4+(1)\omega_5=0
$$
because $(2)\omega_0+(2)\omega_3=0$, and $(2)\omega_1+(2)\omega_4=0$, and $(1)\omega_2+(1)\omega_5=0$. Then regarding the linear independence of $\sum_k c_k \omega_k = 0$ consider the following: Does their exist a non-trivial case?

Note: Evenly spaced under modulo addition of a composite divisor of $n$ means the following: Let $m_p$ be a composite divisors of $n$ such that $n=m_0 m_1 \cdots$, then the trivial case of $c_k$ satisfies $c_k=c_j$ for $(k-j) \mod m_p =0$.

Comment: This is somewhat poorly worded. I think that what you want to ask is whether given integers $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ such that $\sum a_i\omega_i = 0$, must is follow that the nonzero $a_i$ are all equal. Correct?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The case when all $a_i$ are equal is not the most general case in the trivial case mentioned in the OP. This is because $n$ can be a composite number.

Comment: I'm trying to *understand* what you wrote; "that area evenly spaced" is a typo, but even taking that into account I'm not sure what you mean. I don't know what 'evenly spaced under modulo addition' means.If my attempt at understanding it is incorrect, fine, but just telling me I'm wrong doesn't clarify what you are trying to say.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Thank you for pointing out my poor wording and the typo. I have corrected the typo and provide clarification as a note in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your definition correctly but I believe the fact that the [$n$th cyclotomic field extension of $Q$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) has degree $\phi(n)$ says that there are no non trivial combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference. May I ask: how can I improve the wording of my question to address your confusion?

Comment: @linuxfreebird sure, use more maths in your definitions and less words. This is not a general rule but it would help in this case. Could you make sense of my answer? Do you think it answers your original question?